# Django AutoField error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to include the following schema to my django app, but always wind up getting an Assertion Error.
The schema:

```
class Tuple(models.Model):
    fancyId = models.IntegerField()
    file1 = models.FileField()
    file2 = models.FileField()
    ccode1 = models.CharField(max_length=10000,default="123",unique=False)
```

I even tried using the same example as given in the django docs, but wind up with the same error!

The error thrown is this:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 29, in database_forwards
    to_model = to_state.render().get_model(app_label, self.model_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 67, in render
    model.render(self.apps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 316, in render
    body,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 168, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 919, in contribute_to_class
    "A model can't have more than one AutoField."
AssertionError: A model can't have more than one AutoField.
```

Comment: The `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)` is implicit so there's no real reason to add it here

Comment: Is that the actual model that's causing the error? It doesn't seem to match the exception. Another possibility is that an old, incorrect state is still in the migration files. In that case, try removing and recreating the migrations.

Answer (score 4):

Django will automatically generate the primary key `id`, so the `Id` is redundant. see [the Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html).

Unless you are trying to integrating Django with a legacy database. see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: That was just for getting a fancy Id that I create. Updated the model, still the same error!(Changed the Id to fancyId and removed the primary_key=True